# I gave a scammer my name and address; what can they do with that information?

Tags: fraud, scams

I accidentally gave my name and address to a scammer. What can I do? Is that bad? What can they do with that information?

Comment: I can look your name and address up in a phone book. It's public info. Don't be too worried if that's the only info you gave out.

Answer (score 5):

You encountered a quite common scam: You are supposed to perform a job, they send you a check for too much money, and you are supposed to pay them some money back. Ten weeks later the check bounces and your money is gone.

That's these people's job. They do this all day long. The success rate isn't very high, so they are busy doing this all day. These scammers might have your name and address, but if that is all there is, they can get names and addresses of 100s of people by using the phone book, and they don't.

I wouldn't say that it is impossible to turn your name and address into money, but it is hard work. So it is quie unlikely to happen.

Comment: Yeah I know   I was half asleep when it happened but just taking precautions  haha

Answer (score 0):

First off how do you know if they are indeed a scammer?

> What can they really do with that?

Well it depends on the scammer's skill and sophistication.

Ideally with your name and address, they would probably send you mail that attempts to scam you. For example, they might send you a check but will require you to do something in order to receive that money.

If this scammer is very sophisticated they can get your life's story with that information alone.

Comment: It's a babysitting scam where the scammer sends me a check and gives me a reason to  send the money to someone and the check declines but  with my address  they can't find my life story so I think I'm good

Comment: Well from what I know.. A sophisticated scammer can learn your life's story with just the information you gave out... But for your sake I hope your right!

Comment: I'm 17 I don't have a life story  just was worried more about like if they'd try to come to the house

Comment: If you are sending and forwarding checks, I'd be more worried that you might be a scapegoat that gets the rap instead of them if law enforcement gets involved.

Comment: @user36537 I've had something similar happen, but it was the scammers that want your bank account information to send a check from some place.  Never give them your bank account, otherwise you will lose money you can't get back (glad it didn't happen to me).

Comment: This is what the "lady" said  but I was half asleep  but as long as my street address  was only to send the fake check then I'm fine

Comment: Thanks for your quick response to my email, My Name is Jessica Stone
from Canada (Ontario) I'm moving to your area for some weeks having
contract with N.G. O Non Governmental Organization that takes care of
children living with HIV/AIDS we are sponsored by UNI AIDS and A.S. O
Aids Service Organization, I want you to help me Care for daughter
from 3am to 7pm from Monday to Friday for some weeks and I will pay
for 4 weeks upfront Because i have to make sure everything is well
organized and arrange before leaving. My daughter's name is Chloe is 5
years old,
she likes to play around with kids and

Comment: like to be pampered with toys.
My daughter is healthy, i just need someone to take care for her while
am at work, all necessary contracts will be filled when we arrive to the state.
You do not have to worry about transportation, I have negotiated with
a cab Driver that
will be driving her down to your place go and come I would like you to
get back to me with your total charges for 4 weeks during your
available periods because my affiliated company will make an upfront
payment for my 4 weeks in the states to help me settle down. Kindly
send the following details to get your paycheck processed.

Comment: Full name to be on the check :-
Street address (not P. O Box): -
City:-
State:-
Zip code:-
Total charges:-
Mobile number for easier communication:

I will await for the information from you as soon as possible.
Remember she is all i have and i really want a conducive and pleasant
atmosphere for her. We will arrive to the state on 31st of January, start
on the 1st of February 2016.
 Jessica Stone
3600 Steeles Ave E,
Markham, ON L3R 9Z7,

Comment: Well your right about this being a scam. Did you receive anything since then?